# Numbering h1,h2 headings, nested documents that reset counter

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, recursion

I'm looking to add numbers to headers like below.  The problem is that there are documents that may be infinitely nested and need to be counted independently.  In the original document, the headings are text only, with no numbered prefix.

```
<div id="text_output">
  <h1>Document 1</h1>
    <h2>1 Heading</h2>
      <h3>1.1 Subheading</h3>
      <h3>1.2 Subheading</h3>
        <div class="text_output_expansion">
          <h1>Document 2</h1>
            <h2>1 Heading</h2>
              <h3>1.1 Subheading</h3>
            <h2>2 Heading</h2>
              <h3>2.1 Subheading</h3>
        </div>
      <h3>1.3 Subheading</h3>
    <h2>2 Heading</h2>
      <h3>2.1 Subheading</h3>
      <h3>2.2 Subheading</h3>
        <div class="text_output_expansion">
          <h1>Document 3</h1>
            <h2>1 Heading</h2>
              <h3>1.1 Subheading</h3>
            <h2>2 Heading</h2>
              <h3>2.1 Subheading</h3>
                <div class="text_output_expansion">
                  <h1>Document 4</h1>
                    <h2>1 Heading</h2>
                      <h3>1.1 Subheading</h3>
                    <h2>2 Heading</h2>
                      <h3>2.1 Subheading</h3>
                </div>
              <h3>2.2 Subheading</h3>
        </div>
      <h3>2.3 Subheading</h3>
    <h2>3 Heading</h2>
      <h3>3.1 Subheading</h3>
      <h3>3.2 Subheading</h3>
</div>
```

I'll post a CSS solution, but I'm just struggling to get this working in javascript instead.  The idea is so that I can copy and paste the document with the numbers intact (CSS solution won't allow that).  Admittedly my javascript isn't great, but my struggle seems to be how js loops through the elements from top to bottom.

Comment: What's your input?  DOM nodes?  HTML text?  And how about the output?  Can you share some of your own attempts at this?

Comment: Your indentation implies a nesting that doesn't exist in the document.  Is there a chance of altering the structure so that, say, the second `H3` is nested inside the following `DIV` or that some common element wraps them both?

Comment: Unfortunately the structure is locked, I'm using someone else's data which I assume originates from markdown files.

Comment: Then can you alter your expectations for the output?  The real problem to my eyes is that the 1.3 subheading will look visually as though it's nested under `Document 2 > 2 Heading 2`, right after and on a level with `2.1 Subheading`.  That is just going to be terribly confusing.  What about changing the nested headers to fall inside their parent hierarchy?  That is, the headers under the first `text_output_expansion` could become `H4`, `H5`, `H6`, `H5`, `H6` and then would look like they're properly nested.  The problem is when you hit `H8`, and I think you will, but something has to give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recursively traverse the structure by grouping on `h` tag blocks:

```js
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = `<div id="text_output">
  <h1>Document</h1>
    <h2>Heading</h2>
      <h3>Subheading</h3>
      <h3>Subheading</h3>
        <div class="text_output_expansion">
          <h1>Document</h1>
            <h2>Heading</h2>
              <h3>Subheading</h3>
            <h2>Heading</h2>
              <h3>Subheading</h3>
        </div>
      <h3>Subheading</h3>
    <h2>Heading</h2>
      <h3>Subheading</h3>
      <h3>Subheading</h3>
        <div class="text_output_expansion">
          <h1>Document</h1>
            <h2>Heading</h2>
              <h3>Subheading</h3>
            <h2>Heading</h2>
              <h3>Subheading</h3>
                <div class="text_output_expansion">
                  <h1>Document</h1>
                    <h2>Heading</h2>
                      <h3>Subheading</h3>
                    <h2>Heading</h2>
                      <h3>Subheading</h3>
                </div>
              <h3>Subheading</h3>
        </div>
      <h3>Subheading</h3>
    <h2>Heading</h2>
      <h3>Subheading</h3>
      <h3>Subheading</h3>
</div>`
document.querySelector('body').appendChild(div)
```

---

```js
function number_headings(root){
    var h1 = 1;
    function label_headings(nodes, p){
       var [groups, group, h] = [[], [], null]
       for (var i of nodes){
          if (i.tagName[0].toLowerCase() != 'h' || (h != null && i.tagName != h.tagName)){
             group.push(i)
          }
          else if (h === null){
             h = i;
          }
          else{
             groups.push({node:h, block:group.slice()});
             group = [];
             h = i;
          }
       }
       if (h != null){
          groups.push({node:h, block:group.slice()});
       }
       var c = 1;
       for ({node:n, block:b} of groups){
           if (n.tagName === 'H1'){
              n.textContent = `${n.textContent} ${h1}`;
              h1++;
           }
           else{
              n.textContent = `${(p === null ? c.toString() : p+'.'+c.toString())} ${n.textContent}`;
           }
           label_headings(b, n.tagName === 'H1' ? null : (p === null ? '':p+'.')+c.toString());
           for (var k of b.filter(function(x){return x.nodeType === 1 && x.tagName[0] != "H"})){
              label_headings(Array.from(k.childNodes).filter(function(x){return x.nodeType === 1}), null);
           }
           c++;
       }
    }
    label_headings(Array.from(root.childNodes).filter(function(x){return x.nodeType === 1}))
}
number_headings(document.querySelector('#text_output'), null)
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use CSS counters to append text to the headers instead.  Unfortunately, the weakness (or strength) of this approach is that it is visible to the user, but it cannot be copy pasted from the browser, nor is it easy to get the value if you need it elsewhere in your script.

```
#text_output {
  counter-reset: h2
}

#text_output h2 {
  counter-reset: h3
}

#text_output .text_output_expansion .card-body{
  counter-reset: h2
}

#text_output .text_output_expansion .card-body h2 {
  counter-reset: h3
}

#text_output h2:before {
  counter-increment: h2;
  content: counter(h2) ". "
}

#text_output h3:before,
h3.md-focus.md-heading:before {
  counter-increment: h3;
  content: counter(h2) "."counter(h3) ". "
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did another recursive option.  I think Ajax has the best answer tho!

```
function numberHeadings(element) {
var h1_counter = 0;
var h2_counter = 0;
var h3_counter = 0;
var h4_counter = 0;
var h5_counter = 0;
var h6_counter = 0;
element.find(".text_output_expansion").each(function () {
  numberHeadings($(this));
});

element.find("h1:not([numberHeadings=complete]),h2:not([numberHeadings=complete]),h3:not([numberHeadings=complete]),h4:not([numberHeadings=complete]),h5:not([numberHeadings=complete]),h6:not([numberHeadings=complete])").each(function () {
  switch ($(this).prop("tagName")) {
    case "H1":
      h1_counter += 1;
      h2_counter = 0;
      h3_counter = 0;
      h4_counter = 0;
      h5_counter = 0;
      h6_counter = 0;
      $(this).text(h1_counter.toString() + ". " + $(this).text());
      $(this).attr("numberHeadings", "complete");
      break;
    case "H2":
      h2_counter += 1;
      h3_counter = 0;
      h4_counter = 0;
      h5_counter = 0;
      h6_counter = 0;
      $(this).text(h1_counter.toString() + "." + h2_counter.toString() + ". " + $(this).text());
      $(this).attr("numberHeadings", "complete");
      break;
    case "H3":
      h3_counter += 1;
      h4_counter = 0;
      h5_counter = 0;
      h6_counter = 0;
      $(this).text(h1_counter.toString() + "." + h2_counter.toString() + "." + h3_counter.toString() + ". " + $(this).text());
      $(this).attr("numberHeadings", "complete");
      break;
    case "H4":
      h4_counter += 1;
      h5_counter = 0;
      h6_counter = 0;
      $(this).text(h1_counter.toString() + "." + h2_counter.toString() + "." + h3_counter.toString() + "." + h4_counter.toString() + ". " + $(this).text());
      $(this).attr("numberHeadings", "complete");
      break;
    case "H5":
      h5_counter += 1;
      h6_counter = 0;
      $(this).text(h1_counter.toString() + "." + h2_counter.toString() + "." + h3_counter.toString() + "." + h4_counter.toString() + "." + h5_counter.toString() + ". " + $(this).text());
      $(this).attr("numberHeadings", "complete");
      break;
    case "H6":
      h6_counter += 1;
      $(this).text(h1_counter.toString() + "." + h2_counter.toString() + "." + h3_counter.toString() + "." + h4_counter.toString() + "." + h5_counter.toString() + "." + h6_counter.toString() + ". " + $(this).text());
      $(this).attr("numberHeadings", "complete");
      break;
  }
})
```

};